# Removing the injected script through the chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm building a chrome dev tool extension to capture page elements and store. For now, I'm able to capture the page element by using click method in the content script which I've injected. To send the captured element from content script to background script, I used **stopPropagation** and **preventDefault** methods to disable the click event on the element.

**Problem Statement**: Now I would like to revert to the element's default event after selecting an element. This is where I'm stuck on how to revert back.

**manifest.json**:

```
{
    "name": "My app",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "My app",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "file://*/*"
    ]
}
```

The `devtools.html` has `devtools.js` script which creates the new `tab` panel in chrome dev tools and loads the `panel.html`.

**panel.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="insertscript">Insert script</button>
    <button id="clearscript">Clear Script</button>

    <input type="text" id="tagName" />

    <script src="panel.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**panel.js**:

```
(function createChannel() {
    var port = chrome.extension.connect({
        name: "Sample Communication" //Given a Name
    });

    port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
      document.querySelector('#tagName').value = message.tagName;
    });

}());

function sendObjectToInspectedPage(message) {
    message.tabId = chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId;
    chrome.extension.sendMessage(message);
}

document.querySelector('#insertscript').addEventListener('click', function() {
    sendObjectToInspectedPage({action: "script", content: "selectitem.js"});
}, false);

document.querySelector('#clearscript').addEventListener('click', function() {
    sendObjectToInspectedPage({action: "clear-script", content: "clearscript.js"});
}, false);
```

**background.js**:

```
chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
    var extensionListener = function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (message.tabId && message.content) {
            // Attach a script to inspected page
            if (message.action === "script") {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId, {file: "assets/jquery-2.0.3.js"});
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId, {file: message.content});
            } else if (message.action === "clear-script") {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(message.tabId, {code: "document.removeEventListener('click', onClick);"});
            }
        } else {
            port.postMessage(message);
        }

        if (message.type === "selectedElement") {
            sendResponse(message);
        }
    };

    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(extensionListener);
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(function(port) {
        chrome.extension.onMessage.removeListener(extensionListener);
    });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    return true;
});
```

**selectitem.js**:

```
function onClick(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);

    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
        type: "selectedElement", 
        tagName: elem.tagName
    });
}

document.addEventListener('click', onClick, true);
```

Now when I click on `Clear script` method, I wanted to remove the stopPropagation and preventDefault which I added in `selectitem.js`. Because the element which I've selected could be an `Anchor` tag or `Button` or can be anything which is clickable.

I don't know on how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution with the help of this script: https://github.com/oldprojects/Simple-JavaScript-DOM-Inspector/blob/master/inspector.js

Thought this might be helpful for anyone, hence adding this as an answer.

Comment: Please don't hide the answer behind a link to 200 lines of code.  Post the relevant part here.  Did the answer wind up being `document.removeEventListener("click", onClick, true);`?